# Issue loading font

Tags: asp.net, css, fonts

I used this script but it just works for "Opera".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.js"></script>
```

It doesn't work another browsers. I tried this script;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type=“text/javascript”>
  WebFont.load({
    monotype: {
      projectId: ‘xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx’
    }
  });
</script>
```

And I tried this css block;

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    src: url(http://fast.fonts.com/jsapi/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.js) format("truetype");
}
```

It still dosen't work. 
Do you have any ideas? What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe u need to define all of the formats for this font?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Some Font';
    src: url('../fonts/webfont-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/webfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/webfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/webfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/webfont-webfont.svg#TechniczneTTEFNRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I've just web font link. I don't know how can i do this.

Comment: download this font and set like i show u, as a font family use your font face name `font-family: 'Some Font';`, u will have this font locally and u will be sure that all of this fonts are loaded

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have enough 'reputation'